# Parse XHTML, replace image path and close image tags

Tags: regex, linux, beautifulsoup, xhtml

simple issue: I have a lot of XHTML pages in directory, when try to open any of them, Firefox complains:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </img>.
```

since according to XML specs, any tag has to be either closed with its pair or self-closed by including slash (/) at the and of opening tag. I need replace in img closing tag `>` with `/>`. Additionally I want to replace image src path (keep the original name and extension).
so original:

```
<img src="/api/v1/pubs/media/2014/09/tech38173/files/tab02.jpg" alt="Images" width="300" height="4">
```

replace with:

```
<img src="graphics/tab02.jpg" alt="Images" width="300" height="4"/>
```

I need process all xhtml pages in current directory and apply these changes. May be simple regex will be enough for this, even it not recommended for parsing HTML. Please advice.

Comment: might help to provide some examples ... before/broken ... after/fixed; you state ... *'I saw somewhere this regex'* ... can you provide a link to where you saw the regex (so we can gain some context)

Comment: If your documents are not XML well-formed, then you don't have XHTML pages. Which begs the question "what _do_ you have?". If what you actually have are regular HTML pages, then your best strategy is to use an HTML parser to parse each one into a DOM document. and then serialise those documents out as XML.

Comment: the pages are just blanks for subsequent processing, have only div content section, no heading part and no closing html tags.